# After booting headless (no monitor) there's no video output when monitor attached

Tags: 16.04, server, startup, monitor, headless

On an Ubuntu 16.04 server normally run headless (i.e., no monitor), there's no video output, no text at all, when a monitor is attached later.  However if that Ubuntu server is booted with a monitor attached, the video output appears OK.

Comment: The console could be blanked, try hitting the CTRL to wake up. Otherwise try to switch to another console using CTRL-ALT-F2 and back CTRL-ALT-F1.

Comment: I have already tried without success =(